# Accessing remote folder with IIS

Tags: .net, security, iis

I'm having an issue accessing a remote folder (Remote) on via IIS (WebServer).   Running the same code from IIS Express works fine.

I have
1).  Granted "Full Control" to "Everyone" on the folder in question
2).  Given Read/Write access on the shared to "Everyone"

`Directory.Exists("\\Remote\c$\PathToFolder")` always returns false.
`Directory.Exists("\\Remote\ShareName")` also always returns false.

I can access the folder via explorer when remoted in (as myself) on the WebServer.

I would have thought that while probably not an ideal solution, The Everyone/Everything combination would have yielded the result I'm looking for.

Is there a "correct" way to determine why the web server can't access the remote folder that isn't just trial and error?

Thanks
Joe

Comment: The first is an admin share, so that won't work unless the ASP.NET user has admin privilidges on the netowrk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directory.Exists is not trial and error (there's no error part). If you want to know *why* it can't access it, try to open or create a file on the share; the subsequent error might be a bit more informative.

As to why, IIS Express is probably running under your identity; IIS proper probably isn't. It may well not have access to the Network. Check what user it's running as.